# Webpack module cannot be imported in multiple entry config

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my webpack config file, i have multiple entry points:-

```
entry: {
    bundle: "./src/index1.js",
    rUI: "./other/src/js/ui/index2.js"
  },
```

In index1.js file, all imports are getting resolved, but in index2.js which looks like following

```
import someModule from "./components/SomeModule/SomeModule";
export default SomeModule;
```

it's not able to resolve someModule (though the relative path is correct and file exits) and gives error - **Cannot find module "./components/SomeModule/SomeModule"** on browser console...

However, if I bring the entire contents of someModule.js, there is no issues.. which means that there is some problem with path. Not able to figure out why...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a way to help you without more info on the actual source tree bit. Maybe there is a typo in `SomeModule` ?

Comment: No, there isn't any type otherwise if I copy the contents of someModule, it works just fine. But, if I use require it worked... finally I found the problem was to add some additional preset in babel loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Though the same code worked using require instead of import. But to make the same code work, I had to add additional preset - es2015 and react. Something like

`"babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=react,presets[]=stage-0,plugins[]=transform-object-rest-spread"`

Answer (score 1):

Not really a way to solve your problem, but if you are having trouble with import paths, I'd recommend having a look to something like [babel-root-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-import) pluging.

It has saved me so many headaches.